# 2-way SSL authentication / mutual authentication example need in LoopBack

Tags: authentication, ssl, loopbackjs, mutual-authentication

I'm looking for example of implementation of 2-way SSL authentication / mutual authentication example in LoopBack API framework(featured by StrongLoop API Platform)
I need to connect with SOAP API with mutual authentication.

I found these examples
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-ssl and https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-connector/tree/soap ,
but I guess it isn't enough.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Node module [loopback-ssl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-ssl) which can accelerate enabling SSL with loopback.
- SID

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.